# Webdriver Issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I trying to use selenium in `jupyter` notebook on Firefox. I have installed the `geckodriver` in `/usr/bin` directory .When I run my code it says:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

if I run the command `%env PATH` following output is displayed:

```
$PATH:/usr/bin/
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I have even tried

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/geckodriver')
```

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path if it is useful

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are working with geckodriver on the local machine and providing the absolute path for the driver to run, This can be done automatically using [webdriver-manager python](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Advantages of using it are-

1. You don't have to give the path every time to run code.
2. Makes the code portable and easy to run on any machine without checking for geckodriver or chromedriver.

**`pip install webdriver-manager`**

Now the above code in the question can be changed to work simply with,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

If the above doesn't help, try doing this.

autoinstaller for geckodriver-
`pip install geckodriver-autoinstaller`

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import geckodriver_autoinstaller 

geckodriver_autoinstaller.install() #checks for driver or install it. driver = 
webdriver.Firefox() driver.get("python.org")
```

this worked fine for me, otherwise, try to give a full path after downloading the latest geckodriver binary file.

Comment: I tried it, i get following error:                                                                                                       ValueError: Could not get version for Firefox with this command: firefox --version

Comment: update the solution, trying doing it now.

Comment: I tried it  got new error: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'firefox': 'firefox'

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this with a Maven project so you can add dependencies in the pom.xml file. so you dont have to give the path each time. Refer this article [here](https://manulwick.medium.com/using-webdriver-manager-with-maven-pom-dependency-b227a74fdb6d).Its in java but will help.